# Opening and viewing a Git Repository in sublime 3 from Git Bash

Tags: git, sublimetext3, git-bash

I am trying to work with this repository (https://github.com/dappuniversity/dbank) and I have it open in Git Bash. I am learning how to do all of this from a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWFba_9QYmc) and at (09:39) the instructor uses the subl shortcut to open Sublime and the project is just open there.

When I do this, the repo is not open in Sublime Text. Any ideas what  I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` to your PATH through the Control Panel and you should be able to use `subl` just fine once you restart Git Bash.

Comment: So is `subl` working on the command line now?

Comment: Note that the command shown in the video `subl .` just opens a Sublime Text window and sets that window's project to the [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) – the `.` dot on the command line just means the current directory. If you don't want to set the `PATH` all you need do is to open a new Sublime Text window, use `Add Folder to Project` (in the `Project` menu) to add the relevant directory, and -if needed- select `Show Side Bar` (in the `View` menu) so you can select/open the various files in the directory like in the video.